# javascript remove link from div if href exist

Tags: javascript, html

lest say that this is my div:

```
<div id="success">
<a href="/index.php">link1</a>
<a href="/index.php">!AnotherLink!</a>
<a href="cat.php">link3</a>
</div>
```

I want to romove any link from success div that is the **same "href"**

It should be like this:

```
<div id="success">
<a href="/index.php">link1</a>
<a href="cat.php">link3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
function removeDups() {
    var container = document.getElementById("success");
    var a = container.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var hrefs = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].href in hrefs) {
            a[i].parentNode.removeChild(a[i]);
        } else {
            hrefs[a[i].href] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fDPsH/